# At what impact parameter does a meteor hit the surface of a planet?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, meteors

The data I have is only $v_\infty$ and $v_0$, velocity at a large distance and escape velocity respectively. 
I need to find at what impact parameter a meteor strikes the surface of a planet of radius $R$.

Comment: How is "impact factor" defined?

Comment: I'm guessing the impact factor is defined the same way it is defined in a scattering experiment i.e., the perpendicular distance between  the direction $v_\infty$ and centre of the planet.

Comment: Probably textbook mentions something else? Perhaps the trajectory of the meteor is assumed to be tangent to the planet's surface?.. Otherwise it seems to me that the impact factor can be arbitrary.

Comment: I think it is assumed to be tangential.

Comment: Since the escape velocity is solely connected to a planet mass, you have just one parameter for the definition of a meteor dynamics. Then, the impact is arbitrary. You need to define your problem more closely.

Comment: There is a range of impact factors that would imply a striking. You should then find the minimum impact factor to avoid a collision.

Comment: @PruthviBharadwaj in this case you should consider conservation of energy and conservation of angular momentum. If at the point of the impact the velocity is indeed tangential (perpendicular to) the radius, its expression will have an easy form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a continuum range of impact parameters resulting in a striking. If the impact parameter $b$ vanishes they collide. If we infinitesimally change $b$ they still collide. Sou you should find what is the smallest impact parameter such that the asteroid does not strikes the planet. This will happen when the **maximum approach** $r$ between the bodies is less than the radius $R$ of the planet. When they are equal, the asteroid "scratches" the surface of the planet.

You can solve this problem just by using energy and angular momentum conservation (since there is only a central force). At the maximum approach of a conic orbit, $r=R$, there is not radial kinetic energy (the particle is in a returning point), so at this point
$$E=\frac{L^2}{2mR^2}-\frac{GMm}{R}.$$
This shall equal the energy at infinity, $E=\frac{1}{2}mv_\infty^2$.

To eliminate the angular momentum $L$, just compute use the angular momentum of the particle at any point of the trajectory (there is only one point easy to compute it). This angular momentum is written in terms of the impact parameter $b$. Plug this into the above equation and solve for $b$. The answer is
$$b=R\sqrt{1+\frac{2GM}{Rv^2_\infty}}.$$
For any impact parameter less than that, there will be a striking.

The last step is just to use the escape velocity to eliminate $GM/R$.